# Using Hibernate, proper connections to DBMS and how make safe query methods

Tags: java, hibernate

I created Hibernate classes, and several functions that access the DBMS in order to take information. This is my typical code for each method:

```
public void f(){
    SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session=factory.getCurrentSession();

    session.beginTransaction();
    Query<AllNew> query=session.createQuery("select m from "+AllNew.class.getName()+" m");
    List<AllNew> list = query.getResultList();


    for(AllNew i:list){
        ....
    }

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    System.out.println("Done");
}
```

I believe that this essential code has a problem inside. 
Currently the DBMS reaches a high number of open connections so I have reason to believe that: when the method ends, not everything inside obj is closed.

Comment: you may want to close the session by `session.close;`

Comment: You should only have ONE SessionFactory for all you application (or per DB). Each method should only open session (through factory.getCurrentSession()). And at the end of your method you should close the session.

Comment: And do not forget to close the session even if exception occured with a try {...} finaly {session.close();} block.